# Nodejs not able to respond to more than one request for mongoose connection test

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm fairly new to mongoose and node. I am trying to write a simple API using Nodejs and Express, wherein I send a MongoDB URI, and if it is valid, i.e. the username/password combo works and a connection to that URI is successfully established, a success message should be returned.

I initially tried to create a separate function to try to connect to the given URI:

```
function testURI(uri) {
   mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true} );
   mongoose.connection.on("connected", function() { return true } );
}

module.exports.test = function(req, res) {
   var uri = req.body.uri;
   if(testURI(uri)) res.status(200).json({'success': true});
   else res.status(400).json({'success': false});
};
```

But this failed, since mongoose connects asyncronously, and the "connected" event callback is not able to return true for the main function

So I dropped the idea for a separate function, and instead tried to achieve it within the module.exports.test function:

```
module.exports.test = function(req, res) {
   var uri = req.body.uri;
   mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, connectTimeoutMS: 2500 });

   mongoose.connection.on("connected", function() {
       mongoose.connection.close();
       res.status(200).json({'success': true});
   });

 mongoose.connection.on("error", function(err) {
        result = {
            'error': true,
            'errorMsg': 'Error: Could not connect to the given host.'
        }
        mongoose.connection.close();
        res.status(400).json(result);
    });
};
```

This works fine, except that the server dies after responding to one request. Once I try with an invalid URI, it returns HTTP 400 as expected, but then when I send another request with a different URI, the app just crashes with the error

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

And then I have to restart the app before I can send another request. Apparently the two separate  `res.status(200).json` and `res.status(400).json` in the same controller are creating the problem and the app is treating subsequent requests also as the same request.

Comment: Would putting ```return``` in front of the both ```res.status().json``` help you?

Comment: @MatinSasan tried it, doesn't work... Probably because a `return` just exits from the callback function where it resides, and not from the parent function

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by creating a custom middleware. Instead of returning the result via `res.status().json()` within the controller function, I used this function as a middleware and returned the result from the next function

```
module.exports.test = function(req, res, next) {
   var uri = req.body.uri;
   mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, connectTimeoutMS: 2500 });

   mongoose.connection.on("connected", function() {
       mongoose.connection.close();
       req.status = 200;
       req.result = {'success': true};
       next();
   });

 mongoose.connection.on("error", function(err) {
        result = {
            'error': true,
            'errorMsg': 'Error: Could not connect to the given host.'
        }
        mongoose.connection.close();
        req.status = 400;
        req.result = result;
        next();
    });
};

module.exports.returnDb = function(req, res) {
    res.status(req.status).json(req.result);
};
```

Edited route declaration:

```
router.route('/test')
.post(client.test, client.returnDb);
```